# How to clone repo based on Git Parameter Jenkins job using plugins

Tags: git, jenkins, plugins

I use the [git parameter plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Git+Parameter+Plugin) and the [git plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Git+Plugin) in a normal jenkins job.

I define a git parameter. The 'user' can start the job using parameters and has to select a branch.
The git plugin should clone that branch from a the repo using the git plugin. Thanks to the credentials in the git plugin, the git parameter plugin is able to show the current branches.

Now I don't find a way how to use the git parameter in my git plugin.
My config for the git plugin:

```
Branch Specifier (blank for 'any'): ${BRANCH}
```

(In the shell I'm able to echo the content of `$BRANCH` which shows the name of the branch I chose. What am I missing here?

Comment: In pipeline `git credentialsId: '<id>', url: '<repository_address>', branch: BRANCH`

Comment: @minas and is it possible in a freestyle job?

Comment: Of course, in *Branch Specifier (blank for 'any')* you have to write `*/$BRANCH`